# How to hide linked JavaScript file in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, api, resource-leak

I am a beginner and I am learning. Now I am working with API. In some cases, I have to use my private API keys in the JavaScript file. If I publish the webpage somewhere anyone can see the private API keys by clicking on `view page source` on the browser.

I always write JavaScript codes in a separate file and link them with the HTML file by the `script` tag.

Is there any way to hide the JavaScript file or is there any way to prevent the leaking of private API keys?

Comment: You can hide them on the server with authentication and make a request with the password.

Comment: You can't. Everything browser-side is public. All security and all secrets have to be held and done server-side, period.

Answer (score 2):

All the code you put in JavaScript is available to public.
In the common case you need to create kind of middle-server, which proxies your request to api-server with your private credentials.